# How to access javascript variable in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is my code:
In A Function:

```
var daaa=document.getElementById('da').value= year+ "-" +month+ "-" +day;
    document.form1.bookingsession.focus();
var coords = {
    "lat": daaa
};
 $.get('bs.php', coords, function () {
    alert('data sent');
});
```

and my php code is:

```
<?php
$output = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['lat'] : 0;
print("$output");
?>
```

And when i print $output i get the value as 0, but actually have to get the value which is on tha variable daaa. Let me know where i made mistake....
Thank you in advance

Comment: Break it down to the simplest request. Open developer tools console: `$.get('bs.php', { lat: 50 });` - what does the request return?

Comment: It still return the value 0, even after i replaced my coding as $.get('bs.php', { lat: 50 });

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var coords = {
"lat": daaa
};
```

to

```
var coords = {
lat: daaa
};
```

you misplaced the double quotes.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

example from jquery

```
//$.get("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Comment: I replace the quotes but still getting the same error, thank you for your help sir...

Comment: @Ganesh How are you accessing `bs.php`? Means directly opening `bs.php` in browser.

Comment: Clearly the OP wants to send the value of the variable `daaa` to the server, so changing it to `"daaa"` would not really help. I don't know though it he question was changed after you answered.

Comment: By directly opening the `bs.php` in browser it will always give you `0` output. In your code you are sending `ajax` request to `bs.php`, so you can get the value of `daaa` from its response. And also see the edited answer.

Comment: yes Mr.Felix, i need to send the variable to the server, but when i'm printing it on the server side it still shows zero, so please tell me what's gone wrong in code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
var daaa=document.getElementById('da').value= year+ "-" +month+ "-" +day;
```

to

```
var daaa=document.getElementById('da').value + "-" + year+ "-" +month+ "-" +day;
```

Anyway in such cases yours "number one" action should be check if variable is really set on client side. You can do it through alert(daaa) or console.log(daaa);

Comment: I want to send the value of variable daaa to server side to perform some validation...

Answer (score 0):

First of all do the action @coramba mentioned,

then modify your javascript code like this:

```
$.get('bs.php', coords, function (dataThatPhpPrints) {
    alert(dataThatPhpPrints);
});
```

..you will see that it actually returns the value that you have sent to PHP script and PHP scripts returns the print of that.

In order to assure yourself that your scripts prints something modify PHP code to like below:

```
<?php
$output = isset($_GET['lat']) ? $_GET['lat'] : 0;
print("$output - is response from the PHP!!!");
?>
```

Now when you run yor javascript, you will get an alert message like

```
ActualValueOfLATYouSentToPHP - is response from the PHP!!!
```

Bear in mind, if you want to test your PHP whether it works or not, you cant just simply open it in browser and wait for some magic to happen, as it uses $_GET to get some value meaning you need to provide it as a QueryString with the key being 'lat' :

```
yourhost/bs.php?lat=someTestValue
```

Comment: i get the value of daaa in alert box inaddition i receive some script that i return for validation is also shown in the alert, why that script is return on that alert? Thank u for your help sir...